# Can I use PFquery in UIInputviewcontroller, which is class for the keyboard extension

Tags: ios, keyboard, xcode6, pfquery, uiinputviewcontroller

I built a bottom, which generates a PFquery,in the keyboard view; and then insert this queried string in to the textfield by [self.textDocumentProxy insertText: str]. However, when ever I click this button, the keyboard while jump to the next keyboard mode.
please help! thanks and merry christmas.

Comment: Step 1. Show your code.

Comment: -(void)pressSyncPaste{
    
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"currentCopy"];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        
        if(!error){
            
            currentCopy= [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[currentCopy[0] objectForKey:@"copyContent"] ];
        }
        
    }];

        
  }